# replace pandas series values with dict of index and values

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas series with a date index and some values. I also have a dictionary with date keys and some values.
For example:

```
s = pd.Series(np.arange(10), index=pd.date_range('2021-01-01', periods=10, freq='D'))
d = {pd.Timestamp('2021-01-01'):-1, pd.Timestamp('2021-01-05'):-2}
```

I would like to replace the rows with index that exists in the dictionary with the value in the dictionary.

I'm able to do so with:

```
s.loc[d.keys()] = list(d.values())
```

I have a feeling that there is a better way to do this in pandas. Is there any built in function that can do this?

Edit: earlier version had pd.Series(d.values()) which does not work (see Psidom comment)

Comment: Your approach is actually not working, since the index doesn't match, You should just assign a list of values to it. `s.loc[d.keys()] = list(d.values())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`Series.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.update.html) (Note `update` is inplace unlike most `pandas` operations which return an updated copy):

```
s.update(d)
```

*Note the dictionary is converted to a Series via `Series(other)` before attempting to `update` ([source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.3.2/pandas/core/series.py#L3246-L3247))

`s`:

```
2021-01-01   -1
2021-01-02    1
2021-01-03    2
2021-01-04    3
2021-01-05   -2
2021-01-06    5
2021-01-07    6
2021-01-08    7
2021-01-09    8
2021-01-10    9
Freq: D, dtype: int32
```

---

Complete Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(
    np.arange(10),
    index=pd.date_range('2021-01-01', periods=10, freq='D')
)
d = {pd.Timestamp('2021-01-01'): -1, pd.Timestamp('2021-01-05'): -2}

s.update(d)

print(s)
```